# JQuery - $(this).find() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a Material front-end that is built in Bootstrap. Trying to use JQuery to edit the values of a [modal component](http://daemonite.github.io/material/docs/4.1/components/modal/#varying-modal-content):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="formMail" tabindex="-1" rmle="dialog" aria-labelledby="formMailLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="formMail_title">Send</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#formMail').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('It works!'); // <<<< problem here!
    })

</script>
```

I am having issues with the find function. I am not an expert on JQuery but as I am using $(this) I imagined it would be considered a Jquery Object.

The complete error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: modal.find is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (cursos:439)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=3.3.1:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=3.3.1:2)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=3.3.1:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=3.3.1:2)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=3.3.1:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=3.3.1:2)
    at w.fn.init.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=3.3.1:2)
    at o.p.show (modal.js:121)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (modal.js:516)
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Add `console.log(this)` as the first line in the function to determine what `this` is pointing to.

Comment: What if you do `$(event.target)` instead of `$(this)`?

Comment: @Scott: <div class="modal fade" id="formMail" tabindex="-1" rmle="dialog" aria-labelledby="formMailLabel" aria-hidden="true"> <!--omitted--></div>

Comment: what is the context of  _this_?

Comment: The code you've shown here appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/p2c3ozfm/

Comment: Try changing `modal.find('.modal-title').text('It works!');` to `$('.modal-title', this).text('It works!');`

Comment: @Scott: $(...).text is not a function

Comment: I starting to suspect there is something wrong with the environment. This page is rendered inside Wordpress and maybe the problem is somewhere inside all the boilerplate code.

Comment: This may sound stupid, but you could check if the `$` actually is a fully blown `jQuery` library. I've seen it more than once that a jQuery-like thing was implemented behind the `$` variable but only implemented a small subset of jQuery's functionality. Maybe check if the `find` method is defined at all (e.g. via calling `console.log($.fn.find)`). A strong indicator for not having an actual jQuery could also be that `console.log(window.jQuery)` outputs `undefined`.

Comment: What Happens if you change the `var modal = $(this)` to `var modal = $('#formMail')` ? However, considering that `.text()` returns an error as well I Also believe that the jquery library is loaded too early as suggested in Asheesh' answer

Comment: First you should check if `$` really referes to a jQuery at that time, maybe `$` was overwritten by another library. To do so add `console.log('jquery version: ', $.fn.jquery)`, right before `var modal = $(this);`

Comment: But it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it. The problem was caused by an old version of the [Prototype Javascript Frameword](http://prototypejs.org/).

There was a plugin including the script to the Wordpress header.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the jQuery library BEFORE the Bootstrap library? The error looks familiar and I think that was the problem I had.

Comment: I am not at my job now but I will take look at the order WP has included the libs as soon as I get back.

Comment: Just found it. There was an old version of the Prototype JavaScript framework causing it.